# Trying to send email using smtp , with manual set-up of apache-server and php 7.2?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, smtp

I am running my with apache-server and php 7.2. What i am trying to do is to send email using email library in C.I. but i am getting a error which am not able to debug. A bit of help will be appreciated.In gmail , imap option in settings has been enabled. 
 Here, is my code-

```
function emailverification()
    {
             $this->load->library('email');
        ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
                ini_set("smtp_port","465");
                $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
            $config['_smtp_auth']=TRUE;
            $config['smtp_user'] = '******';
            $config['smtp_pass'] = '******';
            $config['smtp_timeout'] = '60';
            $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
            $config['mailtype'] = "html";
            $this->email->initialize($config);

             $this->email->from('******', 'Support Team');
            $this->email->to('*******');

            $this->email->subject('This is my subject');
            $this->email->message('This is the content of my message');

            if ( ! $this->email->send())
            {
                show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
            }
            else
            {
                echo('DONE');
            }

    }
```

I have also tried to change the ports to 25 , 587 and i have changed the host to smtp.gmail.com as well. This i constant error message
'The following SMTP error was encountered: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.'

Below is the code attached , and the browser is giving me following output when i am running the method. Though on editing the ports and host name 'the server is not able to send mail though PHPsmtp' is constant.

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP c62sm82383961pfg.33 - gsmtp 

hello 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [43.252.26.109]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
from: 250 2.1.0 OK c62sm82383961pfg.33 - gsmtp
to: 250 2.1.5 OK c62sm82383961pfg.33 - gsmtp
data: 354  Go ahead c62sm82383961pfg.33 - gsmtp

quit: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
Date: Tue, 30 Apr 2019 12:35:48 +0530
From: "Support Team" <********>
Return-Path: <*********>
To: **********
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?This=20is=20my=20subject?=
Reply-To: <*********>
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
X-Sender: ********
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5cc7f3ccb9ee7@*****.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5cc7f3ccba2cf"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_5cc7f3ccba2cf
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is the content of my message


--B_ALT_5cc7f3ccba2cf
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

This is the content of my message

--B_ALT_5cc7f3ccba2cf--
```

NOTE:

I want to understand that what machine is trying to tell me here,cause i am new to this.
And it will be great help if anyone can help me resolve this bug.I have been working in this for the past week i am not able to resolve.

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP c62sm82383961pfg.33 - gsmtp 

hello: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [43.252.26.109]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
from: 250 2.1.0 OK c62sm82383961pfg.33 - gsmtp
to: 250 2.1.5 OK c62sm82383961pfg.33 - gsmtp
data: 354  Go ahead c62sm82383961pfg.33 - gsmtp
```

P.S.
Don't down-vote cause i trying really hard to get few up points.

Comment: make sure that you already allowed less secure apps to access your account, [check this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en)

Comment: are you testing email on your local server or production server. if local server i will suggest you to use https://mailtrap.io/, it really good for testing emails you can see configurations how to setup CI settings for mail trap.

Comment: **thanks farooq , i will revert back after trying this**

Comment: **yes , its setting is set less secured apps**